# Elasticsearch | Java version problem during installing Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

My machine runs Manjaro.

I cloned **https://aur.archlinux.org/elasticsearch.git**
then ran: `makepkg -si`

my current Java version is: 19 according to: `java --version`:

> openjdk 19.0.1 2022-10-18 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
> 19.0.1+10) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10, mixed mode)

While running makepkg -si I get the following error though:

> What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':build-tools-internal'.
> Java 17 is required to build Elasticsearch but current Java is version 11.

I also installed java 17 by:

```
sudo pacman -S jre17-openjdk-headless jre17-openjdk jdk17-openjdk openjdk17-doc openjdk17-src
```

Still getting the same error. Any idea?

Comment: it says clearly, build-tools-internal'. Java 17 is required to build Elasticsearch but current Java is version 11, hope you are checking your java version in the same folder

Comment: In which folder? I cloned the package then ran the CMD. As I mentioned, current java version on my machine is 19 and I also installed 17.

Comment: you need see java 17 in Elasticsearch folder

Comment: @Amit you sure?!!! I think It's not related to the Elasticsearch folder. I read the code:if (JavaVersion.current() < JavaVersion.toVersion(minCompilerJava)) {
  throw new GradleException("Java ${minCompilerJava} is required to build Elasticsearch but current Java is version ${JavaVersion.current()}.")
}

Comment: You can try to use the docker it automatically handles the dependencies and also memory management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another version of Java installed, that Elastic is locating when it starts, as indicated by the error message you're getting about version 11. This happens commonly when you've been upgrading Java over time and have older versions still lurking about.